# How to use a js file from outside of create-react-app directory, with craco?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, create-react-app, craco

I'm using `craco` for my create-react-app and I'm trying to import a javascript file from another directory, external to the app `src`.

I've heard it is possible but haven't found anything in their documentation about this, at least not from what I've seen.

My app is built using React version `17.0.2`, in case it might help.

Any idea how to acheive this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my question was to add this inside my `craco.config.ts` exported object:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9127#issuecomment-646989707

You need to add this too in the root of the exported object(e.g: `module.exports = { ...`):

```
    webpack: {
        alias: {},
        plugins: {
            add: [], /* An array of plugins */
            remove: [],  /* An array of plugin constructor's names (i.e. "StyleLintPlugin", "ESLintWebpackPlugin" ) */
        },
        configure: webpackConfig => {
            const scopePluginIndex = webpackConfig.resolve.plugins.findIndex(
              ({ constructor }) => constructor && constructor.name === 'ModuleScopePlugin'
            );
      
            webpackConfig.resolve.plugins.splice(scopePluginIndex, 1);
            return webpackConfig;
        }
    },
```